# PyLatex - Using Only Table Rather Than Whole Document

Tags: pylatex

I have created a document base on [this example](https://jeltef.github.io/PyLaTeX/current/examples/longtable.html). But I want to use only table part rather than whole document.
I have spent plenty of time [libraries of PyLaTeX](https://jeltef.github.io/PyLaTeX/current/usage.html#understanding-pylatex). I could not find how I can do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `LongTable` class has the `generate_tex` method, so you can do

```python
from pylatex import LongTable, MultiColumn    

# Generate data table
data_table = LongTable('lll')
data_table.add_hline()
data_table.add_row(["header 1", "header 2", "header 3"])
data_table.add_hline()
data_table.end_table_header()
data_table.add_hline()
data_table.add_row((MultiColumn(3, align='r',
                    data='Containued on Next Page'),))
data_table.add_hline()
data_table.end_table_footer()
data_table.add_hline()
data_table.add_row((MultiColumn(3, align='r',
                    data='Not Containued on Next Page'),))
data_table.add_hline()
data_table.end_table_last_footer()
row = ["Content1", "9", "Longer String"]
for i in range(150):
    data_table.add_row(row)

data_table.generate_tex('tablefile')
```

to create a file `tablefile.tex` containing only the `longtable` environment.